# Typescript Function Parameter Depends on Another Parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I encountered an issue while trying to create a function to format options for dropdown.

This is the code in vanilla JS.

```
const formatOptions = (options, keyAsLabel, keyAsValue) => {
   return options.map(option) => {
    return {
      label: option[keyAsName],
      value: option[keyAsValue],
    }
   })
}
```

Currently, I have tried this code

```
const formatOptions = <T>(
  options: T[],
  keyAsLabel: T,
  keyAsValue: T
) => {
  return options.map((option, i) => {
    return {
      id: i + 1,
      label: option[keyAsLabel],
      value: option[keyAsValue],
    }
  })
}
```

But this code is giving error.

I want to make a strict type checking, but I have no idea how to make the second and the third parameter dependent on the first Parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#handbook-content):

```
const formatOptions = <T>(
  options: T[],
  keyAsLabel: keyof T,
  keyAsValue: keyof T
) => {
  return options.map((option, i) => {
    return {
      id: i + 1,
      label: option[keyAsLabel],
      value: option[keyAsValue],
    };
  });
};
```